# Does config.GetSection not work in Azure Functions? And what is the recommended alternative?

Tags: json, azure, configuration, azure-functions

Azure Function with a complex (List of objects) configuration type is working locally (with that complex type in local.settings.json) but fails to read / create list of objects in Azure (with that complex type in Azure Function configuration settings).  I'm looking for the recommended / optimal way to support that across both platforms / methods of access.

---

This works great in my local.settings.json where I use the configuration builder and pull data out like

```
var myList = config.GetSection("ConfigurationList").Get<List<MyType>>();
```

however this doesn't seem to work in Azure Functions?? Now I think that is because in local.settings.json it is a json file and looks like

```
"ConfigurationList" : [ { "Name": "A", "Value": 2 }, { "Name": "B", "Value": 3 }]
```

while in Azure Functions it is a setting "ConfigurationList" with the value

```
[ { "Name": "A", "Value": 2 }, { "Name": "B", "Value": 3 }]
```

(so there isn't really a "section" in Azure Functions?)

It seems like the "easy" solution to this is to just change the .json to be a quoted string and deserialize the string (and then it would work the same in both places); but that doesn't seem like it would be the "best" (or "recommended" solution)
i.e. something like

```
"ConfigurationList" : "[ { \"Name\": \"A\", \"Value\": 2 }, { \"Name\": \"B\", \"Value\": 3 }]"
var myList = (List<MyType>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(config["ConfigurationList"], typeof(List<MyType>));
```

Which isn't the worst; but makes the json a bit "not as nice" and doesn't "flow" across the two platforms ... if it is what I have to do, fine; but hoping for a more standard approach / recommendation

Comment: You only put the json into the configuration settings of azure function app on azure, right? Maybe on local you can process local.settings.json as a json file, but when on azure, the value in configuration settings is environment variable. There is no section, it just string.

Comment: Please notice that only string values are allowed, and that anything nested will break. Learn how to use nest settings on azure web app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/asp-net-core-settings-for-azure-app-service

Comment: Have you check the documents, any more doubts of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I metioned in the comment, on local you can process local.settings.json as a json file, but when on azure, the value in configuration settings is environment variable. There is no section, it just string.

Please notice that only string values are allowed, and that anything nested will break. Learn how to use nest settings on azure web app(azure functon is based on azure app service sandbox, so it is the same.):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/asp-net-core-settings-for-azure-app-service

For example,  if this is the json structure:

```
{
  "Parent": {
    "ChildOne": "C1 from secrets.json",
    "ChildTwo": "C2 from secrets.json"
  }
}
```

Then in web app, you should save it like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/06/2018-06-11_18h45_57.png))</sub>

Comment: That's a great solution and works really well if it is a known number of Children; but what if there are different number of children objects?  I guess you can just check if null and enumerate in the code? (in the process I have right now I then do a ForEach on myList and do processing for each "entry")

Comment: How did you manage to add an application setting that contains a colon symbol : ?
I got a message "App setting names can only contain letters, numbers (0-9), periods ("."), and underscores ("_")"

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are looking something like this , it seems a list but if it is a simple JObject like

"ConfigurationList" : {
"Name": "A",
"Value": 2
}

Then you can declare ConfigurationList:Name , ConfigurationList:Value in the configuration settings of function app